# Derivative of trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

How i can find the derivative of this trigonometric function

$csc^4(8x^4-5)$

i tried to do it my self and i got to this

$ 4[csc(8x^4-5)]^3 * [-csc(8x^4-5)cotan(8x^4-5)] $

The answer in the book is $ -128 x^3csc^4(8x^4-5)cot an(8x^4-5)$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Use the Chain rule. It makes your approach easier and help you to get the answer better. So set $u=8x^4-5$ while $g=\csc(u)$ and $f=g^4$. You have then: $$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{df}{dg}\times\frac{dg}{du}\times\frac{du}{dx}$$

Comment: I know and i did exactly that and still same. I don't know how he got -128

Comment: @Tennisman: I see that the other answer replied correctly. Note that there is an $4$ in the derivation because of $\frac{df}{dg}$ and also you have a $32$ because of the derivation of $\frac{du}{dx}$.

Comment: yeah i got it. Thanks :D

Comment: @Tennisman: I am glad I could help. :-)

Answer (score 2):

$$\csc^4(8x^4-5)=\frac{1}{\sin^4(8x^4-5)}=-\frac{(\sin^4(8x^4-5))'}{\sin^8(8x^4-5)}=-\frac{4\sin^3(8x^4-5)\cdot (\sin(8x^4-5))'}{\sin^8(8x^4-5)}$$
$$=-\frac{4\sin^3(8x^4-5)\cdot \cos(8x^4-5)(8x^4-5)'}{\sin^8(8x^4-5)}=-\frac{4\sin^3(8x^4-5)\cdot \cos(8x^4-5)\cdot 32x^3}{\sin^8(8x^4-5)}$$
$$=-\frac{128 x^3\cdot \cos(8x^4-5)}{\sin^5(8x^4-5)}=-128x^3\frac{\cos(8x^4-5)}{\sin(8x^4-5)}\cdot \frac{1}{\sin^4(8x^4-5)}$$
$$=-128x^3\cot(8x^4-5)\csc^4(8x^4-5)$$

Comment: Upvote,very clear answer!